# A Master Category Table Where Records Have Various Categories OR There Should Be A Table For Each Category Type

Tags: sql-server, database

Recently I encountered an application, Where a Master Table is maintained which contain the data of more than 20 categories. For e.g. it has some categories named as Country,State and  City.

So my question is, it is  better to move out this category as a separate table and fetching out the data through joins or Everything should be inside a single table.

P.S. In future categories count might increase to 50+ or more than it.

P.S. application based on EF6 + Sql Server.

**Edited Version**

**I just want to know that in above scenario what should be the best approach, one should go with single table with proper indexing or go by the DB normalization approach, putting each category into a separate Table and maintaning relationship through fk's.**

Comment: Can you show the actual structure of the existing table (such as a `create table` statement, or mock up of its data and uniqueness), not just a verbal description of it?

Comment: why downvoted? . i don't think it's a bogus question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, categories are put into separate tables.  This conforms more closely with normalized database structures and the definition of entities.  In particular, it allows for proper foreign key relationships to be defined.  That is a big win for data integrity.

Sometimes categories are put into a single table.  This can, of course, be confusing; consider, for instance, "Florida, Massachusetts" or "Washington, Iowa" (these are real places).

Putting categories in one table has one major advantage:  all the text is in a single location.  That can be very handy for internationalization efforts.  To be honest, that is the situation where I have seen this used.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for quick response!!. We also thought about normalization and currently we are considering each category as a separate table. but I am curious about what happens when more categories will come  up . In Current scope they might move upto 50-60. So In this case does this normalization will scaleup?.can you bit clarify on this internationalization stuff.?? Thanks!!